# pcmanfm doesn't send files to trash on external drive

Tags: fstab, gvfs, trash, pcmanfm

I have a HDD which I mount on `/mnt/sda1` at startup (in `/etc/fstab`)

Whenever I want to send a file to the trash in pcmanfm, I get the following message :

> Some files cannot be moved to trash can because the underlying file
>   systems don't support this operation. Do you want to delete them
>   instead?

The owner of `/mnt/sda1` and `/mnt/sda1/.Trash-1000` is user 1000 (me), and I have read write permissions.

When deleting a file in the CLI using `gvfs-trash` or `gio trash` it correctly sends the file to `/mnt/sda1/.Trash-1000`, and pcmanfm sees the file in the Trash and can even restore it. Still it cannot delete it.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit late, but I ran into the same issue. As it turns out, you have to disable the 'Erase files on removable media instead of "trash can" creation' preference. [Apparently PCManFM sees any drives with an unmount button as removable media](https://github.com/lxde/libfm/blob/b08218e2311dc52465ef92502061738701f298c1/src/job/fm-file-ops-job-delete.c#L351). Once that's done, sending files to trash works as expected.

[image]